# How to test Fragments?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-fragments

*Sorry for my English*

I started to learn how to use TDD in Android Development.

I need to test a `Fragment` in isolation. I used [this tutorial](http://blog.denevell.org/android-testing-fragments.html), but I got exception when I tried to commit transaction (to add `fragment` in `activity`) in test. I found solution - using `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of `transaction.commit()`. But I'm not sure that this solution will always work correctly.

So, now I use something like this:

in application package (not test package) I have package `helper_to_test_fragments` with next classes:

**FragmentBuilder.java**

```
public interface FragmentBuilder {
    Fragment build();
}
```

**CurrentTestedFragmentBuilder.java**

```
public class CurrentTestedFragmentBuilder {

    private static class DummyFragmentBuilder implements FragmentBuilder {
        @Override
        public Fragment build() {
            Fragment dummyFragment = new Fragment() {
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    // inflate empty FrameLayout
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dummy, container, false);
                }
            };
            return dummyFragment;
        }
    }

    private static FragmentBuilder currentFragmentBuilder = new DummyFragmentBuilder();

    public static void setCurrentBuilder(FragmentBuilder fragmentBuilder) {
        if (fragmentBuilder == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("fragmentBuilder should be not null");
        }
        currentFragmentBuilder = fragmentBuilder;
    }

    public static Fragment build() {
        return currentFragmentBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

**ActivityHelperToTestFragments.java**

```
// This activity declared in application Manifest.xml file
public class ActivityHelperToTestFragments extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_helper_to_test_fragments);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment currentTestedFragment = CurrentTestedFragmentBuilder.build();
            getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.containerOfCurrentTestedFragment, currentTestedFragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }

    public Fragment getTestedFragment() {
        return getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerOfCurrentTestedFragment);
    }
}
```

**activity_helper_to_test_fragments.xml** - layout for helper activity above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerOfCurrentTestedFragment" />
```

**Using:**

```
public class TestSomeFragment
         extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityHelperToTestFragments> {

    private ActivityHelperToTestFragments activity;
    private Fragment testedFragment;

    public TestSomeFragment() {
        super(ActivityHelperToTestFragments.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        CurrentTestedFragmentBuilder.setCurrentBuilder(new FragmentBuilder() {
            @Override
            public Fragment build() {
                return new SomeFragment();
            }
        });
        activity = getActivity();
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        testedFragment = activity.getTestedFragment();
    }

    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(activity);
    }

    public void testFragment() {
        assertNotNull(testedFragment);
    }

}
```

What are the drawbacks to this approach? Is this approach correct? How easy it is, in your opinion?

I use static methods for setting the current tested fragment. But I use this solution for testing fragments in isolation.

Please, suggest solution that is better than this.